# How do I access the contents of this variable in PHP?

Tags: php, scope, string-interpolation

I am using a library, XCRUD, which takes a string argument and is expecting a variable interpolation pattern. Here is how it is used in the documentation, which works fine.

`$xcrud->column_pattern('username','My name is {value}');`

I want to use this variable as a key to an array, but I can't figure out what syntax is required to access it.

I have tried the following:

`$xcrud->column_pattern('PlanNo', $myArray['{value}']);`

`$xcrud->column_pattern('PlanNo', $myArray[eval('{value}')]);`

`$xcrud->column_pattern('PlanNo', $myArray[${value}]);`

How is it that the function in the library I'm calling can access the variable through `{}`? Maybe it's unreasonable for me to expect it will exist in the current scope, and it just passes that string somewhere down the line.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: dont really do support for every script ever written

Comment: That's because the former is a string that is parsed by the xcrud rendering system. In the latter you are trying to access an array. You just got things mixed is all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$xcrud->column_pattern('PlanNo', $myArray[eval("(" + value + ")")]);
```

Comment: Brilliant workaround. Thank you. I realize it's a bit silly to have to do this, but there's no other way besides extending the `column_pattern` method itelf. SWEET.